# How to insert a particular column from a DataFrame into a new column of a database table?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame, where column 0 is an ID, column 1 is Name, and column 2 is Total. Column 2 is newly generated.

```
     0        1  2
0    1    Name1  1
1    2    Name2  8
2    3    Name3  6
3    4    Name4  5
```

and so on..

ID is a primary key in an existing table in my database. I created a new column in my table (which originally has two columns ID and Name), labeled "Total" and I want to insert column 1 values into it for each corresponding ID.

I'm currently regenerating the existing table in the DataFrame with the new column Total in the end. Then rewrite the whole table again using df.to_sql(..., if_exists='replace').

Here is my full code for reference:

```
import sqlite3
from pandas import DataFrame

#access the database created
db = sqlite3.connect('database')

c = db.cursor()

c.execute("select ID, Name, count(*) from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID group by ID")
df = DataFrame(c.fetchall())

df.to_sql('table1', db, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: You basically need to manipulate your dataframe to get it into a form where inserting total rows makes sense. That might include pulling down the existing data from your database, merging these two dataframe, and manipulating further prior to calling `df.to_sql(..., if_exists=replace)` or something like that. Can you show what you want the final table to look like along with some example data from the existing table?

Comment: @PaulH I guess I can recreate the whole table, but it seems to be a round about way of doing it as opposed to directly just inserting it. But you're probably right, it probably would be faster than looping and inserting row by row. I will try to recreate the table using a query and replace it with my DataFrame using df.to_sql(..., if_exists=replace)

Comment: @PaulH I tried it your way with to_sql , but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an error. I updated the question with the full code.

Comment: i think you're going about this all wrong. use `pandas.read_sql`

Comment: That worked! :) I'll post the solution for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to do it:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

#access the database created
db = sqlite3.connect('database')

df = pd.read_sql("select ID, Name, count(*) from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID group by ID", db)

df.to_sql('table1', db, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```